# obtain data from html elements and populate others with the info

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I'm currently working on an AJAX-based function to load a youtube video into an existing div. That part is working nicely.

Now I want to modify my code so that I can also grab a hidden title and description for each video and add this data above and below the video (title should be above, and description should be below the youtube video).

The problem is I am not sure who to achieve this modification. here is what I have so far:

My Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function SendValue(v) {
            xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = HandleValue;
            xmlHttpReq.open("GET", "srcsendback2.php?code="+v,true);
            xmlHttpReq.send();
            }


    function HandleValue(Code) {
            if(xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
                if(xmlHttpReq.status == 200) {

                    var Code;
                    var CodeTitle;
                    var CodeDesc;
                    var Code = xmlHttpReq.responseText;

                    CodeTitle = code + "-title";
                    CodeDesc = code + "-desc";



                    document.getElementById('vidtitle').innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('CodeTitle').innerHTML
                    document.getElementById('viddesc').innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('CodeDesc').innerHTML
                    document.getElementById('ytvid').src = document.getElementsByClassName('Code')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href

                    window.scroll(0,0); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets, scrolls page to the top
                } 
            }       
</script>
```

And here is some example html:

```
        <h1 id="vidtitle"></h1>
        <div id="videoDiv">
            <iframe id="ytvid" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xyz" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <p id="viddesc"></p>


        <div id="links">



                <button type="button" name="button" onClick="SendValue('abc')" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/123">Title 1</button> <br />

                <button type="button" name="button" onClick="SendValue('def')" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/456">
Title 2</button> <br />

                <button type="button" name="button" onClick="SendValue('ghi')" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/789">Title 3</button> <br />


            <div id="content" style="display:none;">

                <ul class="media-collection">

                    <li>
                        <div class="m-left">
                            <a href="#">
                        </div>

                        <div class="m-right">

                            <p class="CodeTitle">
                                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/123">
                                    <span class="field-content">Title 1</span>
                                </a>
                            </p>

                            <p></p>

                            <div class="CodeDesc">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur convallis metus et lectus venenatis rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas bibendum nisi ut velit luctus ultricies. Mauris at nibh a elit pretium varius. Nunc accumsan sagittis augue at facilisis. Phasellus et ante lorem, vitae laoreet enim. Donec vulputate, velit a lobortis eleifend, neque nibh rhoncus quam, non pharetra turpis mauris sed ligula. Ut rhoncus, felis ac scelerisque volutpat, turpis elit malesuada ante, vel varius lorem erat dapibus mi. Nullam nulla risus, aliquam sed tempus eu, dictum a est. 
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <p></p>

                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Apologies if I was not able to clearly describe my issue.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To find the title, you can do this:

```
  var p = document.getElementsByClassName('CodeTitle')[0];
  var span = p.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
  alert(span.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Note that when you do this:

```
xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = HandleValue;
```

...you are giving javascript a function that you want js to call at some future date.  And when js calls that function, js is not going to call it with any arguments.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I have various videos to load. So the title, video and description should be filled based on which button is pressed.

Comment: It looks like you already know how to do what I originally posted, so are you having trouble extracting the title and description?  If so, check my answer again.

Comment: Why does your page's html have a 'content' div with the actual title and description embedded in it?  The actual title and description should be in the responseText. It seems to me that your html page should only have two empty divs where you will inject the title and description.  Did you insert the responseText into your html page so that you could parse it? If so, then the code I posted should allow you to get the info you want.